# static constants class causing error when added static readonly property

Tags: c#, static, windows-services, constants, readonly

```
public static class Constants
{

    public const string Fields_Fax = "FAX";
    public const string Fields_DataProtectionPost = "DATAPROTECTIONPOST";
    public const string Fields_DataProtectionTel = "DATAPROTECTIONMOBILE";        
    public const int AddressBookID = 595204;

    public static readonly XName PersonXName = "Person";
```

This class is in a window service solution. The service was installed locally and was running using the values above.

I took over the project and added some static readonly XName types of my own to this class.
Now I get an error "The type initializer for 'This.App' threw an exception" when i use any property from that class.

There is only 1 project and I've recompiled solution and reinstalled the window service. Any idea what the problem is?

The exception is:

```
"The type initializer for 'Constants' threw an exception"
```

...the inner exception is:

```
"The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."
```

...I commented out my changes and it was reading correctly with no errors. So I added just 1 line which looks similar to the "Person" constant but caused it to fail:

```
public static readonly XName cor_Tel_GeneralXName = "Tel General";
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `PersonXName = new XName("Person");`?

Comment: @reniuz The exception is "The type initializer for 'Constants' threw an exception"...The inner exception is -{"The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."}...I commented out my changes and it was reading correctly with no errors. So I added just 1 line which looks similar to the "Person" constant but caused it to fail... public static readonly XName cor_Tel_GeneralXName = "Tel General";

Comment: @insanepaul I'm pretty sure you need to use the `new` construct with all non-native objects - see my comment above

Comment: @scibuff That line was already there. I've added a similar line which causes the error

Comment: Is it something to do with these values being installed in the IL and i need to somehow reinstall them?

Comment: Seems a blank in "Tel General" is causing all the fuss. Could you check Xname's constructor? There might be a validation of some sort, or a `.Name = ` that throws exception.

Comment: change "Tel General" to "TelGeneral" and it should work

Comment: @scibuff `XName` has [an implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx) which allows you to create an instance 'directly' from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XName` is used as an XML node, and so is subject to the usual restrictions for naming XML nodes. You can't have a space in the name of an XML node.

Comment: I changed it as you and @Reniuz suggested and it worked! Annoyingly it bombed out on the other XName constants so I didn't pick up on it.

Comment: Ah well, all's well that ends well :)